# Mount VMWare Disk on OSX

Tags: vmware-fusion

I have a VMWare Fusion guest running CentOS 7.

I am having an issue with starting the VM and the recommended solution is to remove a file in my home directory.

Here are the things I have tried:

1. **Grub:** Grub allows me to see the file, but does not allow me to remove it.
2. **MacFuse:** This tool will not download for me. The sourceforge site just hangs. I did not try to hard to resolve it because I hate sourceforge and anything on that site turns my stomach.
3. **Paragon VMDK Mounter:** Gave me an error message that it could not open this type of disk.

Anything else I should try?

Should I hold my nose and try to get MacFuse installed?